# LINQ 2 SQL : Loading more than one result sets to a variable when executing a stored procedure from LIN2 SQL

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

In LINQ 2 SQL,I am executing a stored procedure like

```
  datacontext.StoredProcedureName(parameter1,paramter2)
```

My sotored procedure is returning 2 different resultsets.How can i catch it and parse over it to grab the values from it

VB.NET am working with

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at a box to test this out, but, however you are executing the sproc, that method will need to return a collection of tables.  You'll then be able to go through them.

Now, as a nasty old DBA / Developer - sprocs should always return 1 and only 1 resultset / table.  Always.  Unless exceptions get in the way, and I don't count those.  Cause if I counted those, I would go crazy.

No really, 1 method ( stored procedure ), 1 action, 1 returnset ( table ).